# How to calculatie frequency of recombination between two genes based on their coordinates in ENSEMBL?

Tags: genomics, recombination

I have two genes:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/326619 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/326620

both are mapped to chromosome 13. First is at position 23944778..23945232 second is at positions 23940920..23941369. Is there a way to compute approximate recombination rates between the two based on position? I need this for predicting efficiency for maintaining stable linkage between genes for a mouse cross.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend consulting a mouse recombination map. Hopefully no need to compute anything, as you should be able to just look up recombination rates between named SNPs.

- [Here is one mouse map publication.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/22562932/)
- [Here is another one.](https://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/182/4/1335.full.pdf)

I'd suggest taking a look at those and figuring out if they have the information you need.